# Check if value exist or exclude repeated values array

Tags: php, arrays

This the array...

```
$rt = array(
    '0' => array(
    'nombre'=>'Jojo',
    'fecah'=> '195',
    'fch'=>'12'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'nombre'=>'Tito',
        'fecah'=> '197',
        'fch'=>'13'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'nombre'=>'Jojo',
        'fecah'=> '195',
        'fch'=>'12'
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'nombre'=>'Joji',
        'fecah'=> '195',
        'fch'=>'12'
    ),
);
```

and this is my code:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($rt as $k=>$v) {
    if (in_array($v['nombre'], $a) && in_array($v['fecah'], $a) && in_array($v['fch'], $a) ) {
        $a[]=$k;
        echo 'The name ' . $v['nombre'] .' is in the array<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'The name is not in the array <br>';
    }
}
```

so as you can see  in the array index [2] the information also exist in the index [0], so I don't need it again, so I need a away to see if the data get repeated or not... if the data is "unique" then build the new array with the "unique" data if the data already exist then jump to next, but I need to compare the 3 keys not just the name... so how do I do that?

Comment: Yes and no, with that I only get a unique "array", which is fine, but what I need to know what arrays or values are repeated? ...

Comment: If you get the unique array, you can then do a diff to find the repeated values.

Comment: dimmit!... you are totally correct, I don't know what I'm thinking... so.. I get the unique arrays `$unique_arrs` and then I just do a `$repeated_arrs = array_diff($unique_arrs, $rt);`... correct?

Comment: ok, that didn't worked... as far as I know `array_diff()` only work on simple arrays not multidimensional arrays, so I guess I have to build a second array for each array, `$arr2[] = $an->name . ' ' .$an->fecah;` and so on like a single string but then is the matter to retrieve the information, which I can put the ID at the end then just `substr();` whatever i need and build a 4th query to view the information... well, like you said in theory it might work... thanks...

Comment: It's conceptually what you need to do - go back to the duplicate I flagged, and instead of returning a unique array (multidimensional), return the common values if that is what you want. `array_diff()` will work in the same way with that function if you are serializing everything

Comment: Actually yes, that might work, but, I'm doing what I just find in this url http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#37527 with that I got all the unique "array" and another array for the repeated arrays, that did the trick... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You insert array when it is in_array and you use AND

you should reverse your codes like this

```
$a = array();
foreach ($rt as $k=>$v) {
    if (!in_array($v['nombre'], $a) || !in_array($v['fecah'], $a) || !in_array($v['fch'], $a) ) {
        $a[]=$k;
        echo 'The name ' . $v['nombre'] .' is in the array<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'The name is not in the array <br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, it's a multi dimensional array so you can't use `in_array()` to check whether the keys exist within it since they will be a level deeper than `in_array()` checks for.

Comment: What i see is he tries to insert each deeper level of array into one dimension array

Comment: You say `if(!in_array($v['nombre'], $a))` - but `$a` is an array like: `array(0 => array('nombre' => 'whatever, 'etc' => 'foobar'))` - won't work.

Answer (score -1):

This is you need this

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($rt as $key => $value)
{
    $nombre = $value['nombre'];
    if(!isset($newarray[$nombre])) 
    {
       $newarray[$nombre] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the question - "I need to compare the 3 keys not just the name"

Comment: thats what I already have, I need to check for multiple keys of the arrays...